# How to use the rxjs "find" operator

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to set `nameMatch` to the `nodeName` if the `nodeName` is present in the observable stream. The same with `idMatch`. I'm trying to use the `find` rxjs operator. This is what I currently have:

```
 const response = 
(this._resourceService.search(ResourceUrns.SERVICE_METRIC)

            .pipe(
                map(getServiceNodes))
            .subscribe(result => {
                if (result.find(nodeName)){
                    this.nameMatch=(nodeName);
                 } else{
                this.nameMatch= "not present"
                }
                if(result.find(systemId)){
                    this.idMatch=systemId
                } else {
                    this.idMatch='not present'
                }
                }));
```

I'm getting "predicate is not a function" in the console when I try to log it.

Comment: You're not trying to use the rxjs find operator. The only operator you're using here is `map()`. You're using (I guess) the find() method of Array: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find. RxJS operators transform an observable into another observables, and are used inside `.pipe()`

Comment: Can you provide more code ? It looks like 'result' is not an array, or you may have an error in getServiceNodes function

Comment: I guess issue is here `result.find(nodeName)`. `find` accepts function as argument. Is nodeName a function?